# IAM Policy is not giving access to the accesspoint

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam

With this policy:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListStorageLensConfigurations",
            "s3:ListAccessPointsForObjectLambda",
            "s3:GetAccessPoint",
            "s3:PutAccountPublicAccessBlock",
            "s3:GetAccountPublicAccessBlock",
            "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "s3:ListAccessPoints",
            "s3:ListJobs",
            "s3:PutStorageLensConfiguration",
            "s3:CreateJob"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]
```

}

I am allowed to access a specific s3 accesspoint. However, when I try using a more specific access which only gives s3:* actions to a specific accesspoint:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListStorageLensConfigurations",
            "s3:ListAccessPointsForObjectLambda",
            "s3:GetAccessPoint",
            "s3:PutAccountPublicAccessBlock",
            "s3:GetAccountPublicAccessBlock",
            "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "s3:ListAccessPoints",
            "s3:ListJobs",
            "s3:PutStorageLensConfiguration",
            "s3:CreateJob"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:eu-west-1:598276570227:accesspoint/accesspointname"
    }
]
```

}

This does not work, and the EC2 with this role stops being able to access the s3 access point (just copying a file using the AWS CLI)

First why is this happening? The role still should have access to all the actions on that accesspoint by my reckoning (which must be wrong in some way!).

Secondly, I am trying to make it such that an s3 bucket is only accessible from a certain IAM role. I tried setting this from the access policy from the access point itself. This had the opposite problem that it was too permissive and everything could still access it. What is the correct way of doing this - putting an IAM policy on the accesspoint to restrict access to the IAM role or making an IAM Role which has access to this s3 access point?

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by using this:]

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListStorageLensConfigurations",
            "s3:ListAccessPointsForObjectLambda",
            "s3:GetAccessPoint",
            "s3:PutAccountPublicAccessBlock",
            "s3:GetAccountPublicAccessBlock",
            "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "s3:ListAccessPoints",
            "s3:ListJobs",
            "s3:PutStorageLensConfiguration",
            "s3:CreateJob"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringLike": {
                "s3:DataAccessPointArn": "arn:aws:s3:eu-west-1:598276570227:accesspoint/accesspointname"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}